# Is there a term like "antonym" but for words of opposite sentiment?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, terminology, antonyms, emotions

I like to play a game where I take a descriptive word with an emotional bias (i.e. describing something "good" or "bad") and I try to think of a word with roughly the same meaning but with the opposite emotional bias. Put differently: (rough) synonyms, but of opposite sentiment.

For example:

- nit-picking vs. detail-oriented
- fanatical vs. passionate
- careless vs. relaxed
- flimsy vs. delicate
- smelly vs. fragrant
- overgrown vs. lush
- gullible vs. trusting
- stubborn vs. steadfast
- controlling vs. attentive
- extravagant vs. luxurious
- know-it-all vs. knowledgeable
- meek vs. modest

Words with opposite meaning are called antonyms, but is there a term for words of similar meaning with opposite sentiment?

Comment: These are words which might be listed as synonyms in a thesaurus even though they have rather different meanings.  I don't know if it's fair to say that the difference is one of "sentiment". For example, something is "flimsy" when it is not strong enough for a given purpose, in fact, much weaker than it should be. The difference vis-a-vis *delicate* is not one of attitude merely.

Comment: I'm inventing *connotation pairs* as an offering for these frenemies.